# Why does MariaDB 10.1.2 blow away MySQL 5.6.22 in sysbench?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, benchmark, query-performance

## Problem

Maria DB is doing roughly twice the number of transactions that mysql is using standard oltp benchmark.

The VM and db's are both **fresh installs from vendor apt repos** with **default configs**.

## VM [Virtualbox 4.3.10]

```
1 cpu

ubuntu 14.04 [fresh install guest machine on virtualbox 4.3.10]

sysbench 0.4.12
```

## Methodology

```
sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=50000 --mysql-db=test --mysql-table-engine=innodb --mysql-user=root prepare


sysbench --test=oltp --oltp-table-size=50000 --oltp-test-mode=complex --oltp-read-only=on --num-threads=1 --max-time=60 --max-requests=0 --mysql-db=test --mysql-user=root run
```

## MariaDB 10.1.2 Result

```
OLTP test statistics:
    queries performed:
        read:                            1149876
        write:                           0
        other:                           164268
        total:                           1314144
    transactions:                        82134  (1368.89 per sec.)
    deadlocks:                           0      (0.00 per sec.)
    read/write requests:                 1149876 (19164.41 per sec.)
    other operations:                    164268 (2737.77 per sec.)

Test execution summary:
    total time:                          60.0006s
    total number of events:              82134
    total time taken by event execution: 59.7102
    per-request statistics:
         min:                                  0.22ms
         avg:                                  0.73ms
         max:                                170.77ms
         approx.  95 percentile:               1.24ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           82134.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   59.7102/0.00
```

## MySQL 5.6.22 Result

```
OLTP test statistics:
    queries performed:
        read:                            506296
        write:                           0
        other:                           72328
        total:                           578624
    transactions:                        36164  (602.73 per sec.)
    deadlocks:                           0      (0.00 per sec.)
    read/write requests:                 506296 (8438.17 per sec.)
    other operations:                    72328  (1205.45 per sec.)

Test execution summary:
    total time:                          60.0007s
    total number of events:              36164
    total time taken by event execution: 59.7937
    per-request statistics:
         min:                                  1.04ms
         avg:                                  1.65ms
         max:                                 97.15ms
         approx.  95 percentile:               2.10ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           36164.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   59.7937/0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

The MariaDB has a lot of optimizer features not found in mySQL (especially 5.5, but still compared to 5.6)

See [this link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/optimizer-feature-comparison-matrix/) for a comparison of optimiser features.

There is also a [benchmark results](https://mariadb.com/blog/mariadb-53-optimizer-benchmark) page which shows MariaDB faster in a lot of tests.

So in the end MariaDB has more options when choosing an execution plan.